# joinining within a category

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have a record of temperatures which have records of the form:

> year, day, temperature

And I'd like to get the first day of each year when the temperature exceeded 100.
Right now I can get it using set of queries below...is there a way to combine it into a single query?

```
select day,year from t
where temperature>100 and year=2000
order by day limit 1;

select day,year from t
where temperature>100 and year=2001
order by day limit 1;

select day,year from t
where temperature>100 and year=2002
order by day limit 1;

select day,year from t
where temperature>100 and year=2003
order by day limit 1;
```

Comment: what RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select year, min(day) as first_day
from t
where temperature > 100
group by year
order by year
```